# bluetooth.service running, but bluetoothctl says "org.bluez.Error.NotReady"

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, broadcom, bluez

my raspberry pi 3 model B, running Arch, has an issue with bluetooth. First of all:

- Bluetooth has worked flawlessly previously
- pi-bluetooth from the AUR is up to date
- bluez and bluez-utils are up to date
- The system is up to date as well (just ran pacman -Syu)

Still, when I try to use the bluetooth interface, it doesn't work.

bluetoothctl (as root), when I run "scan on", tells me

```
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.NotReady
```

wminput can't find the bluetooth interface:

```
No Bluetooth interface found
unable to connect
```

"systemctl status bluetooth" has the following output:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-03-23 21:32:47 CET; 9min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 2005 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1404)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─2005 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 23 21:32:47 media.lan systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 23 21:32:47 media.lan bluetoothd[2005]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Mar 23 21:32:47 media.lan systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 23 21:32:47 media.lan bluetoothd[2005]: Starting SDP server
Mar 23 21:32:47 media.lan bluetoothd[2005]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

I am at my wits end here, everything seems to be fine, yet nothing works. What is going on here?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Okay, wow, turns out all I had to do was run

```
bluetoothctl power on
```

Answer (score 75):

I got the same problem. It turned that the @turf answer didn't work for me.

After I checked `rfkill`:

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

I ran the command:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

And the Bluetooth worked again.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Rafael, does anyone know how this kind of thing can happen? I don't think I did anything different except maybe a system update on Arch Linux

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: In my case, `rfkill` output all no's, but `bluetoothctl` indicated that the power was off

Answer (score 5):

In my case the solution was:

```
bluetoothctl power on
```

followed by

```
rfkill unblock all
```

hci0 was soft blocked.